# flip animation for navigation based application

Tags: iphone, animation, navigation, back-button, flip

How can I use a flip animation for backbarbuttonitem in a navigation based application, which by default acts as a pop to previous view from which we navigated from? I just want to add flip animation to my navigation based application.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will need to replace the default back button with a custom back button. It will not be an arrow button, because as far as I am aware, the arrow navigation button only exists in a private API.

To create your button, do something like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *customBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(flipPopView)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBackButton;

[customBackButton release];
```

Next you need to create the `flipPopView` method to actually flip back:

```
- (void)flipPopView {

    // animateView should be whichever view you want the animation to occur in.
    UIView *animateView = self.navigationController.view;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:animateView cache:YES];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

I based this off of some of my similar code, but it might work differently for you. Let me know if you have problems, and I'll see what I can do.